# Adding relationship in virtual tables

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have these tables and they are not `persisting in the database`. I use them to test a library:

```
defmodule TestModel.Join do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @fields [:public_name, :personal_name, :pass]
  @primary_key false

 schema "" do
  field(:public_name, :string, virtual: true)
  field(:pass, :integer, virtual: true)
  field(:personal_name, :string, virtual: true)
  belongs_to(:where, TestModel.Where, define_field: false, foreign_key: :first_name)
 end

 def changeset(data) when is_map(data) do
  %__MODULE__{}
  |> cast(data, @fields)
  |> apply_changes()
 end
end
```

The belongs_to relationship works fine but I also need to add has many relationship in the where table

```
defmodule TestModel.Where do
  @moduledoc false
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @fields [:first_name, :last_name, :personal_id]
  @primary_key false

  schema "" do
    field(:first_name, :string, virtual: true)
    field(:personal_id, :integer, virtual: true)
    field(:last_name, :string, virtual: true)
  end

 def changeset(data) when is_map(data) do
   %__MODULE__{}
   |> cast(data, @fields)
   |> apply_changes()
 end
end
```

How can I add `has_many relation` for join table in this where model?

This won’t work:

```
has_many(:joins, TestModel.Join)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issues with `belongs_to` in the first place. `foreign_key` should [specify the key in this table](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3), not in the referenced one. Then `has_many` would work as expected:

```rb
# in Join schema
belongs_to(:where, TestModel.Where, foreign_key: :where_id)

# in Where schema
has_many(:joins, TestModel.Join, foreign_key: :where_id)
```

One cannot has one-to-many relationship without a foreign key in the belonging table.